# How to change body of email in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, email

I want to put something like order same packet and if I finish my order I want send email; how can I modify this code to change change the body of the email?

inappemailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface inappemailViewController :
UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
}

-(IBAction)email;
@end
```

inappemailViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)email {

    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123@abc.com", nil]];

        [composer setSubject:@"subject here"];

        [composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];

        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];

        [composer release];

    }

    else

        [composer release];

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"

message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]]

delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];

        [alert release];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }

    else {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The message body is set on this line:

```
[composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];
```

So just change "message here" to whatever you want the email to say. You could also make it be an NSString object that you set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this code. Your message body is set on this line:

```
  [composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];
```

Hope this helps.